# Simulate button click in the viewDidLoad

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uibutton, uitextview

I'm doing an essay app that shows a list of quotes when the user presses a button.
The thing is that when the app is loaded, the UITextView that should show the quotes is empty, and it only gets filled when the button gets tapped.

Is there a way to fill that UITextView? like calling the method that executes when the user taps the button or something like this?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> like calling the method that executes when the user taps the button or something like this?

Absolutely. You'll have connected your button to a method that looks something like this:

```
-(void)buttonPressed:(id)sender
```

You can call this just as you would any other method:

```
[self buttonPressed:nil];
```

I'm passing `nil` as the sender argument in case you do things to the button in this method.